TI NDK rebuild issue
i have download the ndk 2.21.02.43 and copy the ae66 lib files to my own project,rebuild my own project it works well.but if i rebuild the ndk,and then copy the ae66 lib files to my own project,rebuild my project ,it shows some errors.
enter image description here
I don't know what was wrong?
i have refer the link here to rebuild the ndk.text.my software versions:
xdctools 3.22.03.41
bios:6.32.03.43
compiler:c6000 7.4.1(i can't find the c6000 compiler of 7.2.0 as the release note)
ndk 2.21.02.43

The linker can't find the files mentioned in that pic and that's about all we can tell from this.
